# How would you use VisualSVN to maintain both local and remote source paths?

Tags: svn, visualsvn, vendor-branch

How, if it is possible, would you use VisualSVN to retrieve source code from an open source project (such as on codeplex), but also have your own SVN repository locally such that you could keep a revision history for your own customizations, but still once and a while check the codeplex project for changes that I might want to apply to my code. This particular project (on codeplex), I only have read-only access so I would never be checking code back up to to codeplex.

I am relatively new to VisualSVN, having only ever used Visual Source Safe in the past.

Is this type of setup even possible with the tools I have, and if not would another tool work? A few pointers would be a great help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/) has a more thorough explanation than I could possibly give here, but the concept you're describing is [vendor branches](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.vendorbr.html).

I'm not familiar with VisualSVN specifically, so I can't give you any step-by-step howto info; Perhaps someone else will be able to.

Comment: The great thing about "vendor branches" is that they're not a "thing" in themselves, but rather a general technique that can be applied in any source control system.

Comment: Thanks...that is all I needed, a keyword to use for further reading. Hard to google something if you don't know what it is called.